# Locate Java path from Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, path, locate

**Does anyone know how to locate java.exe path using Delphi?**

I'm starting Java application in Delphi program and I need java.exe path. I used google, but I didn't find anything :(

I can't use constant path because some systems have 64 bit java, some 32 bit, some people install java on D: drive...

---

I will use this http://jstart32.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstart32/trunk/src/template/

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Not sure who our audience is but reading this blog post might help. http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: "... small native programs that load the Java Virtual Machine from a DLL/shared library and then feed your program to that JVM using the Invocation API..." I found this in article, but I didn't understand how to make this launcher... Can you help me with some examples of starting java program using this method?

Comment: what about Launch4j http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thank you! I will use this source http://launch4j.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/launch4j/launch4j/head_src/head.c?revision=1.14&view=markup

I hope it can help me

Comment: stop... this code is for C++, it's hard for me to port it on Delphi,sorry :( can you give me another example?

Comment: try launch4j, http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: wow! i found Delphi analog! http://jstart32.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstart32/trunk/src/template/

Comment: which java.exe? there can be more than one version installed on a computer, and you need to know which one your app needs

Comment: @mjn, this whole thing is quite pointless, anyways, like ignoring the whole car whilst comprehensively caring about left rear wheel.

Comment: user539484 obviously - the basic question is: how do I find a file with Delphi? :)

Comment: Alina jstart32 seems to assume that java.exe is in the OS search path already

Comment: Thanks, mjn. I will use C++ for my launcher, it's not so hard to find examples of java executing